# bootstrap to WordPress conversion

Tags: wordpress, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-2

I searched both stack overflow and the web without any really good resources. What is the best way to take a downloaded bootstrapped template and use it as a WordPress theme. Traditionally, I would go through the process of building all the WordPress files and then implementing bootstrap but I must be doing something wrong.

Comment: There are literally hundreds if not thousands of WordPress themes made from Bootstrap. I searched Google for "WordPress Bootstrap Theme".  138,000 Results were returned. Surely, one of them has what your looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here ya go -

[Tutorial using Bootstrap 2.3.2](http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/responsive-wordpress-bootstrap-theme-tutorial)

Comment: I run into problems when I'm trying to register the scripts in the functions.php.

Comment: The theme of trying to convert has some scripts in the footer and some in the header. I'm missing something, but I'm not sure how to problem solve. Any simple solutions to this functions.php error.

Comment: You should always put your scripts in the footer.

Comment: and it's probably 'best practice' if you start a new question for that error.